# Tricky Python question about variable scope

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

I often have variables in my Python projects that I need to share between modules. I know this can be done with args to function calls, but sometimes, it's more convenient to create a single global_vars.py module, and add any variables that need to be shared there, which is what I often end up doing. These variables can then be imported from any other module, and easily shared. This generally works fine for me. Sometimes though, some unexpected stuff happens.

Ex:

I have 3 files:

main.py:

```
from global_vars import var
from mod import modify_variable

print(f"{hex(id(var))} - address of var in main module after import")
modify_variable()
print(f"{hex(id(var))} - address of var in main module after modify_variable() call")
```

global_vars.py:

```
var = 'hi'
print(f"{hex(id(var))} - address of var during import")
```

mod.py:
from global_vars import var

```
def modify_variable():
    global var

    print(f"{hex(id(var))} - address of var before modifying it in modify_variable()")
    var = 'hello'
    print(f"{hex(id(var))} - address of var after modifying it in modify_variable()")
```

If you run main.py with Python3, you get output that looks like this:

```
0x7f0f993bb7f0 - address of var during import
0x7f0f993bb7f0 - address of var in main module after import
0x7f0f993bb7f0 - address of var before modifying it in modify_variable()
0x7f0f993bb870 - address of var after modifying it in modify_variable()
0x7f0f993bb7f0 - address of var in main module after modify_variable() call
```

Basically, everything behaves as expected until we call `modify_variable`.
Within `modify_variable`, the address of `var` starts out as we expect.
Then we assign a new string to it. This does a few things:

- It creates a brand new string in memory
- It changes `var` to point to the address of this new string
- The garbage collector would presumably, at some point, clean up the old string's address

Given this, I would expect that the last check of the address of `var` would also point to the address of the new string. Therefore, I would expect the result to look like this:

```
0x7f0f993bb7f0 - address of var during import
0x7f0f993bb7f0 - address of var in main module after import
0x7f0f993bb7f0 - address of var before modifying it in modify_variable()
0x7f0f993bb870 - address of var after modifying it in modify_variable()
0x7f0f993bb870 - address of var in main module after modify_variable() call
```

but it doesn't. `var` within `modify_variable`, and `var` within main.py now point to completely different addresses, and can no longer share the same data.

What happened? From what I've read, if I hadn't used `global var` in `mod.py`, it was possible that I would have created a local variable with the same name as the global `var` variable, which could cause the symptoms above, but using `global var` as I do ensures I'm dealing with `global_vars.var`, doesn't it?

Comment: If global variables are a common thing in your code, you should back up and look at the way you're laying out your modules. Globals tend to make code harder to read, scope harder to reason about, and if they actually are _variables_ and not constants (for which I recommend something like [dotenv](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv)), can make the behavior of your code non-deterministic in some cases. If passing args around bothers you enough to use globals, though, I'd suggest rethinking your architecture habits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The spec

Python doesn't really have global variables. Here's what python [defines](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/executionmodel.html#binding-of-names) as global:

> If a name is bound at the module level, it is a global variable. (The variables of the module code block are local and global.)

And the [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/simple_stmts.html#global) statement means:

> It means that the listed identifiers are to be interpreted as globals.

i.e. as module-level variables.

If you look at what [`import`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) does:

> 1. find the module specified in the from clause, loading and initializing it if necessary;
> 2. for each of the identifiers specified in the import clauses:
>
>    [...]
>
>    4. [...] a reference to that value is stored in the local namespace, using the name in the as clause if it is present, otherwise using the attribute name

## Your case

So, `global_vars.var` points to address `0x7f0f993bb7f0`, and when you import it to `mod`, it becomes `mod.var` which also points to `0x7f0f993bb7f0`.

When you do `global var` you tell the Python parser to bind `var` to `mod.var`, and then with `var = 'hello'`, you make `mod.var` point to `0x7f0f993bb870`.

But in `main.py`, `var` binds to `main.var`, which was assigned by the `import` statement to `global_vars.var`, namely `0x7f0f993bb7f0`.

## What to do

Implement globals as attributes of a single global object:

`g.py`:

```
class Global:
    pass

g = Global()

setattr(g, 'var', 'hi')

print(f"{hex(id(g.var))} - address of var during import")
```

`mod.py`:

```
from g import g

def modify_variable():
    print(f"{hex(id(g.var))} - address of var before modifying it in modify_variable()")
    g.var = 'hello'
    print(f"{hex(id(g.var))} - address of var after modifying it in modify_variable()")
```

`main.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
from g import g
from mod import modify_variable

print(f"{hex(id(g.var))} - address of var in main module after import")
modify_variable()
print(f"{hex(id(g.var))} - address of var in main module after modify_variable() call")
```

Output:

```
0x7ff2a47a1998 - address of var during import
0x7ff2a47a1998 - address of var in main module after import
0x7ff2a47a1998 - address of var before modifying it in modify_variable()
0x7ff2a47ae500 - address of var after modifying it in modify_variable()
0x7ff2a47ae500 - address of var in main module after modify_variable() call
```